# Internal Server Error Azure Dev Ops Server 2019

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

I have inherited an non working AzureDev Ops 2019 server.
I have been tasked to fix it.
The only thing I seem to be able to access is the Administration console.
The site collections (which I am guessing the should look like websites) just show a web structure.
It is like it is missing the default page.
When I try to modify the "group membership" or "administer security" I get "Http 500 internal server error. Please contact your administrator. There was an error contacting the server".

I have tried repairing Azure DepOps but to no wail.
Can anyone please point to information on how to fix or trouble shoot issues on a DevOps 2019?
I have looked at application logs and IIS logs but there is nothing useful there.
thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your Administration console and IIS?